# how to install Gimpshop/Gimphoto in 12.04? (and what to remove first)

Tags: 12.04, installation, gimp

Here's what I've done:

1. installed GIMP
2. removed GIMP
3. autoremoved GIMP
4. downloaded Gimphoto .deb package

I'm new to installing things out of terminal/software center. What did i miss? What should I really do?

Or, maybe Gimphoto/Gimpshop can't be installed in 12.04?

Comment: Have you double clicked on the downloaded package? It is supposed to open in Software Center and ask your password to install it

Comment: i did, and i got


`Failed to open file '/usr/local/gimphoto/etc/gimp/2.0/controllerrc': open() failed: No such file or directory`


and


`There was an error parsing the menu definition from toolbox-menu.xml: Failed to open file '/usr/local/gimphoto/share/gimp/2.0/menus/toolbox-menu.xml': No such file or directory`

Comment: I just checked the official site of [gimphoto](http://www.gimphoto.com), and their latest .deb package dates back to dec' 2010 and it's based on Gimp 2.4.3. Maybe it cannot be installed as such on Ubuntu 12.10. You've got another chance by using directly the "linux installer file". Remember to delete/backup your preferences. Instructions [here](http://www.gimphoto.com/2008/02/gimphoto-for-linux.html). If this works, post what you've done.